# Understanding the linear cipher decryption process

Tags: linear-cryptanalysis

Being new to Cryptography, I'm having a hard time understanding the basic concepts.

[image: a busy cat]

I understand all parts except why 4 power -1 has become to 7.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Lookup modular multiplicative inverse. Its basically what division becomes on modular rings.

Answer (score 2):

First note the $\pmod{27}$ at the end, which tells us that all these equations are to be taken [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) $27$.

Also note that $4^{-1}$ literally means ["the number $x$ such that $x\cdot4=1\pmod{27}$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) (much like with the real numbers where $4^{-1}=\frac14$ with $4^{-1}\cdot 4=\frac14\cdot 4=1$).

Finally observe that $7\cdot 4=28\bmod 27=1$ and it follows that $7=4^{-1}\pmod{27}$.